# Deleting photos from Hotmail / Skydrive

Tags: onedrive, photos, lumia

I'm a Lumia 925 user and I accidentally sent a couple of photos to Hotmail. The 'sent to Skydrive' button in my settings is deactivated so I can't see them in my account on photo.live.com, but I can't delete them on my phone either.
Is there a way of deleting them from Hotmail?

Answer (score 0):

Delete them from Skydrive first(login to outlook/hotmail/microsft and delete them from there) and later sync-up your Window Phone to Hotmail(Skydrive). That way these photos will automatically get Deleted from your Device.